# Kubernetes NFS PV: Lock reclaim failed

Tags: linux, kubernetes, nfs, kubernetes-pvc

### Configuration:

NFS server and the k8s cluster(single node cluster) run on two machines and use the same OS and NFS software, as below:

```
[root@test-2 ~]# yum info nfs-utils
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn
 * extras: mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn
 * updates: mirrors.huaweicloud.com
Installed Packages
Name        : nfs-utils
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 1.3.0
Release     : 0.68.el7
Size        : 1.1 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : base
Summary     : NFS utilities and supporting clients and daemons for the kernel NFS server
URL         : http://sourceforge.net/projects/nfs
License     : MIT and GPLv2 and GPLv2+ and BSD
Description : The nfs-utils package provides a daemon for the kernel NFS server and
            : related tools, which provides a much higher level of performance than the
            : traditional Linux NFS server used by most users.
            :
            : This package also contains the showmount program.  Showmount queries the
            : mount daemon on a remote host for information about the NFS (Network File
            : System) server on the remote host.  For example, showmount can display the
            : clients which are mounted on that host.
            :
            : This package also contains the mount.nfs and umount.nfs program.

[root@test-2 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)
[root@test-2 ~]# uname -a
Linux test-2 3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Aug 7 18:08:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@test-2 ~]# cat /etc/exports
/home/nfs 192.168.0.0/24(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,insecure)
```

K8S version: v1.17.9

### Problems:

The application(a statefulset) running on k8s is using a PV that was dynamically provisioned by the [k8s-nfs-provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner), the PV is actually backed by a directory on remote NFS server. The application is keeping "CrashLoopBackOff" because it hits "input/output error" constantly when writing some data to the PV after only a few seconds of running.

Meanwhile, I saw a lot of errors in /var/log/messages:

```
Dec  2 17:11:36 localhost kernel: NFS: nfs4_reclaim_open_state: Lock reclaim failed!
Dec  2 17:11:36 localhost kernel: NFS: nfs4_reclaim_open_state: Lock reclaim failed!
Dec  2 17:11:36 localhost kernel: NFS: nfs4_reclaim_open_state: Lock reclaim failed!
Dec  2 17:11:36 localhost kernel: NFS: nfs4_reclaim_open_state: Lock reclaim failed!
Dec  2 17:11:36 localhost kernel: NFS: nfs4_reclaim_open_state: Lock reclaim failed!
Dec  2 17:11:36 localhost kernel: NFS: nfs4_reclaim_open_state: Lock reclaim failed!
Dec  2 17:12:05 localhost kernel: NFS: nfs4_reclaim_open_state: Lock reclaim failed!
Dec  2 17:12:05 localhost kernel: NFS: nfs4_reclaim_open_state: Lock reclaim failed!
Dec  2 17:21:41 localhost kernel: NFS: nfs4_reclaim_open_state: Lock reclaim failed!
Dec  2 17:21:41 localhost kernel: NFS: nfs4_reclaim_open_state: Lock reclaim failed!
Dec  2 17:21:41 localhost kernel: NFS: nfs4_reclaim_open_state: Lock reclaim failed!
Dec  2 17:21:41 localhost kernel: NFS: nfs4_reclaim_open_state: Lock reclaim failed!
Dec  2 17:21:42 localhost kernel: NFS: nfs4_reclaim_open_state: Lock reclaim failed!
```

I took a tcpdump until hit "Lock reclaim failed" in system log, and found there are many NFS errors as below:

- NFS4ERR_BADSESSION (10052)
- NFS4ERR_STALE_CLIENTID (10022)
- NFS4ERR_NO_GRACE (10033)

I'm not sure if they're related to the "lock reclaim failed" or the "input/output" error.

I have encountered this problem on different machines with different machines from time to time and it really annoys me.

Anyone knows the root cause or how to fix it? Big thanks in advance.

### Screenshots

- application pod log
  [image: application log]
- NFS errors in tcpdump
  [image: NFS errors in tcpdump]
- `nfsstate -m` output on k8s
  [image: nfsstate -m output on k8s]
- `nfsstate -c` output on k8s, NOTE the high `open_noat` value.
  [image: nfsstate -c output on k8s]
- NFS server configuration (my k8s node is 111.1.30.16)
  [image: NFS server configuration 1]

Comment: Did you eventually find out what was going on?

Comment: I also have this problem. Did you resolve it?

Comment: No I did not find the root cause and I finally gave up and switched to other storage systems. I heard someone tried client using NFSV3 + nolock(mount options) without problems but I did not verify it.